# What is the preferred way to get a device path for CreateFile() in a UWP C++ App?

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, device

I am converting a project to a UWP App, and thus have been following guidelines outlined in the MSDN post [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/porting-from-setupapi-to-cfgmgr32). The existing project heavily relies on CreateFile() to communicate with connected devices.

There are many posts in SO that show us how to get a CreateFile()-accepted device path using SetupAPI's [SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120(v=vs.85).aspx) Is there an alternative way to do this using the PnP Configuration Manager API? Or an alternative, user-mode way at all?

I had some hope when I saw this [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/bluetooth/bthecho/bthcli/app/main.cpp) in Windows Driver Samples github, but quickly became dismayed when I saw that the function they used in the sample is ironically not intended for developer use, as noted in this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549753(v=vs.85).aspx) page.

Comment: `not intended for developer use` this is not true. in what your problem ? for local machine you can use functions without *_Ex* suffix

Comment: `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Ex` with 0 in last param *HMACHINE   hMachine* have the same effect as [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538463(v=vs.85).aspx) - so simply use this api

Comment: In the github sample, they use CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Ex to somehow get a device path; does the non-Ex function have the same capability?

Comment: from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538463(v=vs.85).aspx) is the "device instance id" the same as the device path? Maybe this is the source of my confusion.

Comment: `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` call `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Ex` with  `HMACHINE hMachine = 0` so for local computer yes - it absolute the same. [*Device Instance ID*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids) this is not a path which can be used in `CreateFile` call. this is absolute different thing.

Comment: and about code in your example - returning string is *multiple, NULL-terminated Unicode strings, each representing the symbolic link name of an interface instance.* so here can be more than 1 path. and can be empty path - also. so in general you need in loop enum path

Comment: something like this `while (*sz) { /*CreateFile(sz,..)*/ sz += 1 + wcslen(sz);}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are showing me here then; I'm trying to get the device path. I need find a method that gives me the device path that does not involve setupapi. I'm not sure how what you are talking about can help with me get the device path; which I need to use with CreateFile().

Comment: `sz` - this i mean string in place `devicePath` in example. this example show you how give device path and this worked. in what problem ? not compiled, error executed ?

Comment: How do I get the device path; I'm not asking how do I use it.

Comment: Also please speak using the eloquent English you have used in other answers on your history page. I'm sure it won't be a problem as all of the previous comments are all intentional; unless they are not?

Answer (score 0):

function [`GetDevicePath`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/bluetooth/bthecho/bthcli/app/main.cpp#L147) in general correct and can be used as is. about difference between `CM_*(..)` and `CM_*_Ex(.., HMACHINE hMachine)` - the `CM_*(..)` simply call `CM_*_Ex(.., NULL)` - so for local computer versions with  and without `_Ex` suffix the same.

about concrete [`GetDevicePath`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/bluetooth/bthecho/bthcli/app/main.cpp#L147) code - call `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size` and than `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` only once not 100% correct - because between this two calls new device with this interface can be arrived to system and buffer size returned by `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size` can be already not enough for `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List`. of course possibility of this very low, and you can ignore this. but i prefer make code maximum theoretical correct and call this in loop, until we not receive error other than `CR_BUFFER_SMALL`. also need understand that `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` return multiple, NULL-terminated Unicode strings - so we need iterate here. in [example] always used only first returned symbolic link name of an interface instance. but it can be more than 1 or at all - 0 (empty). so better name function - `GetDevicePaths` - note `s` at the end. i be use code like this:

```
ULONG GetDevicePaths(LPGUID InterfaceClassGuid, PWSTR* pbuf)
{
    CONFIGRET err;

    ULONG len = 1024;//first try with some reasonable buffer size, without call *_List_SizeW

    for(PWSTR buf;;) 
    {
        if (!(buf = (PWSTR)LocalAlloc(0, len * sizeof(WCHAR))))
        {
            return ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
        }

        switch (err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(InterfaceClassGuid, 0, buf, len, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
        {
        case CR_BUFFER_SMALL:
            err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&len, InterfaceClassGuid, 0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);
        default:
            LocalFree(buf);
            if (err)
            {
                return CM_MapCrToWin32Err(err, ERROR_UNIDENTIFIED_ERROR);
            }
            continue;

        case CR_SUCCESS:
            *pbuf = buf;
            return NOERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

and usage example:

```
void example()
{
    PWSTR buf, sz;
    if (NOERROR == GetDevicePaths((GUID*)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME, &buf))
    {
        sz = buf;
        while (*sz)
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);

            HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(sz, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                // do something
                CloseHandle(hFile);
            }

            sz += 1 + wcslen(sz);
        }

        LocalFree(buf);
    }
}
```

so we must not simply use in returned DevicePath**S** (*sz*) only first string, but iterate it

```
    while (*sz)
    {
      // use sz
        sz += 1 + wcslen(sz);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a valid Device Path to a USB Hub Device, and used it successfully to get various device descriptors by sending some IOCTLs, by using the function I posted in [my own answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56853238/6059640)

I'm reporting the same function below:

This function returns a list of NULL-terminated Device Paths (that's what we get from `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List()`)

You need to pass it the `DEVINST`, and the wanted interface `GUID`.

Since both the DEVINST and interface GUID are specified, it is highly likely that `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List()` will return a single Device Path for that interface, but technically you should be prepared to get more than one result.

It is responsibility of the caller to `delete[]` the returned list if the function returns successfully (return code 0)

```cpp
int GetDevInstInterfaces(DEVINST dev, LPGUID interfaceGUID, wchar_t**outIfaces, ULONG* outIfacesLen)
{
    CONFIGRET cres;
    if (!outIfaces)
        return -1;
    if (!outIfacesLen)
        return -2;

    // Get System Device ID
    WCHAR sysDeviceID[256];
    cres = CM_Get_Device_ID(dev, sysDeviceID, sizeof(sysDeviceID) / sizeof(sysDeviceID[0]), 0);
    if (cres != CR_SUCCESS)
        return -11;

    // Get list size
    ULONG ifaceListSize = 0;
    cres = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size(&ifaceListSize, interfaceGUID, sysDeviceID, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);
    if (cres != CR_SUCCESS)
        return -12;

    // Allocate memory for the list
    wchar_t* ifaceList = new wchar_t[ifaceListSize];

    // Populate the list
    cres = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List(interfaceGUID, sysDeviceID, ifaceList, ifaceListSize, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);
    if (cres != CR_SUCCESS) {
        delete[] ifaceList;
        return -13;
    }

    // Return list
    *outIfaces = ifaceList;
    *outIfacesLen = ifaceListSize;

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that, as RbMm already said in his answer, you may get a `CR_BUFFER_SMALL` error from the last `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List()` call, since the device list may have been changed in the time between the `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size()` and `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List()` calls.